# How to retain values in checkboxlist of struts2?

Tags: database, struts2, checkboxlist

Hi all I am doing checkbox list for a field in JSP of Struts2 application.

**Code in JSP:**

```
<s:checkboxlist list="subjectList" name="subjects"/>
```

**In action Class:**

```
I have used some if/else condition to get the selected checkbox values in Action class as follows.

if(this.getSubjects().trim().contains("CSC"))
        subject.setCSC("true");
    else
        subject.setCSC("false");
if(this.getSubjects().trim().contains("ECE"))
        subject.setECE("true");
    else
        subject.setECE("false");
```

Storing the output object **subject** in Database. It working fine.
In Table have the fields CSC(true/false), ECE(true/false) like that.

Now i want to retain the checkboxlist options as like database value. If the field is true it have to be in SELECTED, if the field is false it should be UNSELECTED in Jsp.

So how to retain the values in checkboxlist from database values. If it is a single checkbox can easily set the value field. If it is list box how to proceed.

Welcome to more suggestion for this task. Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: if i read it correctly you want to auto-check on page load?

Comment: @UmeshAwasthi: You are correct. Auto-check on page Load. Thank you So much.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One easy solution is to create two list (`arrayList` or any collection based list ) one should contain all the values of check-box which can be used to create check-boxes in your JSP, other list should contain only those values which are selected. Say you need to have something like

```
public class MyAction extends ActionSupport{

   List<String> checkBoxList;
   List<String> selectedCheckBoxList
   // getters and setters 

    public String execute() throws exception{

       checkBoxList=getAllCheckBoxes();  // fill this will all list values selected and unselected
        selectedCheckBoxList=selectedCheckBoxes(); // only selected
        return SUCCESS;
   }

}
```

In you jsp all you need to do this

```
<s:checkboxlist list="%{checkBoxList}" name="checkBoxList" value="%{selectedCheckBoxList}"/>
```

Comment: Awesome Umesh Awasthi.                                          Really Your Code helped me a lot to solve this checkboxlist selection.  I have used the following in my jsp:                                       <s:checkboxlist list="subjectList" name="subjects" value="selectedCheckBoxList"/>.                                      Thanks a Lot!!!